# Tweaking the order of UINavigationController ViewControllers NSArray

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uinavigationitem

I want to start my app with a 'HomeScreen' that (amongst some other options) displays a button to choose an image and to resume editing with some image from a previous session.

- Button: Pick
- Button: Edit

When choosing "Edit" it will bring the user to an edit view, using Navigation controllers etc. fine so far
When choosing "Pick" it will show the iOS imagePickerController etc.

but, after selecting an image, I do not want to return to the 'HomeScreen'. When the UIImagePickerController is being dismissed, it will need to 'uncover' the "Edit" view, as if it had been inserted into the 'ViewControllers NSArray', just below the UIImagePickerController.

The 'Back' button in the 'Edit' stage will ALWAYS bring the user back to the 'HomeScreen', so even if one had entered this screen through the imagePicker, it still will have to return to the 'HomeScreen'

One of the reasons that the 'HomeScreen' needs to be the back button, is the the app will be FREE app, but at the HomeScreen will be the option to do IAP to unlock more features and more like the 'About' etc...

So... how can I tweak the order of the Navigation Controller

or are there better ways to go from A to B to C and back to A (or from A to C and back to A)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Bar Button Item on the top left hand side of the scene for 'C' (this will override the back button that automatically gets placed there).

Next create an IBAction for that button that does something like this:

```
- (IBAction)goToA:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Wow. that was way more simple then I expected (as with anything I struggle with for days) - but then instead of dismissing the UIImagePicker, I'd have to make a new segue to 'C'. --- by the time hitting the 'back button' in 'C' and having it Animated:YES, will that slide back all the ViewControllers one-by-one, or all at once and slide straight to the 'RootViewController' ?

Comment: This method goes immediately to the root view controller and pops all of the others off the navigator stack.

Comment: After all it wasn't that difficult at all, it was way more easy, see my own answer below

Answer (score 0):

inside `homeViewController.m` it was just a matter of setting up the right things for the segues:
dragged in a viewController and wired it up to the 'Edit'-button, InterfaceBuilder creates the segue and gave it the identifier `presentImageEditorViewController`. Then as usual, setup the segues in the implementation file (for convenient, I skipped the part of setting up the imagePicker etc).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"presentImagePickerController"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
        NSLog(@"Presenting ImagePickerController");
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"presentImageEditorViewController"]) {
        NSLog(@"Presenting ImageEditorController");
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"Picked some image");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"presentImageEditorViewController" sender:self];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

At the time of selecting an image in the imagePicker, it calls the delegate methode `didFinish…` and simply setup the segue to the `ImageEditorVieController` and then dismisses the `ImagePickerController`, the back button will be just fine in the imageEditor navigationBar